# Kerio Connect Attachments missing after moving mails

Tags: linux, email, attachments, kerio

I got kerio connect as mail server. The host is running on Linux.
I moved mails from a public folder to a local user. Now all my attachments are missing. Is there a way to recover them?

What I tried:
munpack [path]/#msgs/filename.eml ->
tempdesc.txt: File exists /
Did not find anything to unpack from [path]/#msgs/filename.eml

The correct result would be the attachment type.